# How do I change find result highlight color with VS2010 and Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I just installed Resharper and it's changed the highlight color for find results. Normally when I place my cursor on a particular symbol, say a variable called 'goat', all onscreen references to goat will be highlighted with a gray background. When I hit Ctrl+F to move through all references to goat in the document the current find result has the same gray background as all others on screen. So I have no idea which goat I'm currently at until I close the find dialog at which point the currently selected goat highlights in blue.

This makes it really difficult for me to quickly check all references to a given variable in file. I know you can change color settings in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors, however I've been unable to find a setting that corresponds to the currently selected find result.

If the currently selected find result was any color other than gray, it would stand out, but as it is it makes Find as effective as simply clicking on a variable and having VS2010 highlight all current onscreen references.

Comment: ReSharper has its own menu item at the top. Check its options.

Comment: I've checked there. ReSharper color settings are embedded in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting to change is "Inactive Selected Text". It is in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors, Show Settings for Text Editor, third option down.

Comment: That's it, but what I can't figure out is why ReSharper changes how the native VS Find dialog box highlights things.